# Python Reading a text file

Tags: python, applescript

I wrote an applescript to generate a text file of all unwatched movies in my itunes library.  Here is the code of that script:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0
    set unwatchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is true
    if (count unwatchedEpisodes) > 0 then
        set trackNames to {}
        repeat with anEpisode in unwatchedEpisodes
            set tmp to location of anEpisode as text
            set posixtmp to POSIX path of tmp
            set end of trackNames to (posixtmp as text)
        end repeat

        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}

        set unwatchedTVShows to trackNames as text
        do shell script "echo " & quoted form of unwatchedTVShows & " > /Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi/unwatchedTVShows.txt"
        #display dialog trackNames as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end if

    set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "Movies" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0
    set unwatchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "Movies" whose unplayed is true
    if (count unwatchedEpisodes) > 0 then
        set trackNames to {}
        repeat with anEpisode in unwatchedEpisodes
            set tmp to location of anEpisode as text
            set posixtmp to POSIX path of tmp
            set end of trackNames to (posixtmp as text)

        end repeat

        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}

        set unwatchedMovies to trackNames as text
        do shell script "echo " & quoted form of unwatchedMovies & " > /Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi/unwatchedMovies.txt"
        #display dialog trackNames as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end if
end tell
```

Here is my output file:

```
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thanks For Sharing.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thats My Boy.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man Too.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/This Means War.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Top Five.m4v
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Trail of Blood.m4v
```

My problem is reading this file.  I need to open it, and put it in a string so that I can search it wholeistically (ie, if I search for "Think Like a Man" I don't want a false positive on "Think Like a Man Too".

Anyway, here is my current python code (or at least a snippet of that code):

```
KODIFOLDER="/Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi"
with open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt", 'r') as umovies:
    for line in umovies:
        line = line.strip()
        print line
```

Here is the output:

```
/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Trail of Blood.m4voo.m4v
```

Clearly, it's opening and reading the file, but I'm not understanding why the snippet isn't providing a full "list" of what's in the text file.  Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the final answer.  Not sure exactly what's different than what I had before (mixing tabs and spaces maybe??).  Anyway, for future reference, this code:

```
with open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt", 'r') as uwmovies:
    for line in uwmovies:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        unwatchedmovies = line.split('\r')
        print unwatchedmovies
```

Gave the output of this list:

```
['/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Table 19.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Term Life.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thanks For Sharing.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thats My Boy.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man Too.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/This Means War.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Top Five.m4v', '/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Trail of Blood.m4v']
```

which was exactly what I needed.  I list with no "\r" or "\n"'s.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hope my answer helped, if it did please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Because the end of line of your text file is a **carriage return** (Mac, not Unix), use `set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, linefeed}` (**linefeed** instead of **return**), and your original python code will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code snippet?

```
KODIFOLDER="/Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi"
with open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt", 'r') as umovies:
    for line in umovies:
        line = line.strip()
    print line
```

This would only print the last line of your file. Note, `print line` is only indented one `tab`.

Comment: Yes, it's indented correctly...must have been a copy and paste issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.read()` on the file you open and then split the content up on `\n` (newline)

```
KODIFOLDER="/Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi"
with open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt", 'r') as umovies:
    for line in umovies.read().split('\n'):
        line = line.strip()
        print line
```

But this is probably enough for your usecase:

```
KODIFOLDER="/Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi"
with open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt", 'r') as umovies:
    umovies_content = umovies.read()
    print umovies_content
```

Comment: The first example gave me: /Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Trail of Blood.m4voo.m4v

Comment: So did the second...I wasn't expecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ( **Pythonic Way**, UPDATED ) :

```
import sys

read_lines = [sys.stdout.write(line.rstrip('\n') + "\n") for line in open('1.txt')]
```

Python 2x

```
from __future__ import print_function
read_lines = [print(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open('1.txt')]
```

Comment: This gave me: ['/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thanks For Sharing.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Thats My Boy.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Think Like a Man Too.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/This Means War.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Top Five.m4v\r/Volumes/Data/Media/Movies/Trail of Blood.m4v']

Comment: you just do print(read_lines)?! you should print(line.rstrip('\n')) ... did you try that? see my update

Comment: it doesn't like the print being in the line like you have it now.  I got a syntax error:         read_lines = [print(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open(KODIFOLDER + "/unwatchedMovies.txt")]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Brian: because you are on pyhon 2 ( print function will not work in inline for loop on pyhton 2) ! replace print() with sys.stdout.write()...see my update again.

Comment: @Brian: see my update ... print() added by from __future__ import print_function

Comment: @Brian : future is a standard library... do not worry.